# Attempting to map within React returning undefined

Tags: reactjs

I have the following Mongoose schema:

```
const SubmitDebtSchema = new Schema ({
  firebaseId: String,
  balance: [{
    balanceDate: Date,
    newBalance: Number
  }]
});
```

This database schema is called in my parent component using the useEffect hook, and passed down as props to my child component.

```
const fetchDebts = debts.map (debt => {

      return (

       <IndividualDebtCard key={debt._id}
        transactions={debt} />

            )
        })
```

I then store the prop in my child component as a variable, and use another useEffect to console the result of this variable upon rendering:

```
const debts = props.transactions

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(debts)
  }, [debts])
```

For reference, this is what an example console log would look like:

```
    balance: Array (2) 
0 {_id: "5fea07cd143fd50008ae1ab2", newBalance: 1500, balanceDate: "2020-12-28T16:29:00.391Z"} 
1 {_id: "5fea0837b2a0530009f3886f", newBalance: 1115, balanceDate: "2020-12-28T16:30:45.217Z"}
```

What I then want to do, is map through this variable, pick out each 'newBalance', and 'balanceDate' and render them on my page.

However, I'm getting an undefined error every time I try to load my component...

This is what I've tried so far:

```
{ debts.map(debt => {
            return (
            <div className="transaction-history">
                  <div className="transaction-history-entry">
                    <p>{debt.balance.balanceDate}</p>
                    <p>-£{debt.balance.newBalance}</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              )
          })}
```

Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong? I know it'll be something obvious, but can't figure it out.

EDIT: I think the undefined is coming from how I'm attempting to call my 'balanceDate' and 'newBalance' - if I console log what I'm trying to map it's returning undefined.

Comment: If you fetching data async, try `debts?.map`

Comment: Fetching the data isn't the issue, it's about accessing the object within the array and mapping through each of them to render.

Comment: There is no `balance` property in `debt` - just use `debt.balanceDate` and `debt.newBalance`

Comment: There is a balance property.... It's the property which contains balanceDate and newBalance.

Comment: That's not what your console log says.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed that would be obvious considering the Mongoose schema so left balance out. I've edited the console log to reflect that balance is a property, and it's an array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for `debts` to have value. try this:

```
{
  debts.balance && !!debts.balance.length && debts.balance.map((debt, index) => {
    return (
      <div key={index} className="transaction-history">
        <div className="transaction-history-entry">
          <p>{debt.balance.balanceDate}</p>
          <p>-£{debt.balance.newBalance}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  });
}
```

Comment: This isn't right unfortunately - it's not returning anything.

Comment: that's because the `debts` have no value or it's not an `array`, try to log `debts` just before using it to see what's inside of it

Comment: I have console logged debts. It's an array of objects. I provided an example in my original question.

Comment: I know, I saw that. but you're saying you're getting nothing in the output which has the reasons I mentioned in the previous comment. you need provide the whole component code so we could see what's going on in your code

Comment: I've altered the console log to show the full detail and include 'balance'. It's accessing each of them inside which is the problem I believe.

Comment: so the `debts` is an `object` which has a property called `balance` which is an array! . in this case you need to the above check

Comment: That's still not working I'm afraid. Still returning undefined. I'm convinced it's because there needs to be another map through the balance array.

Comment: I can't help anymore if you don't show more code

Comment: try to create a sandbox to demo your code